# How to combine column data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to combine column B from a total of 24 sheets into a master column using formula NOT VBA. Each column B could have up to 500 part numbers. 
So this will give me a master column on a new worksheet of up to 12000 numbers.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the mentioned column B refers to same sheet in all files ??

Comment: Yes. All sheets are identical in layout. Unfortunately I am doing this from my phone and am unable to supply a sample

Comment: I would advise you to use the query option in Excel ( data Tab). you can consolidate the data as mentioned!!

Comment: Is there a way to get the query to update automatically? Or does it need to be refreshed on every change in the reference data?

Comment: you may use refresh option!! if you want anything to be done automatically then you might want to go for VBA.